# How to debug "java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow"?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

There's a Spark job that uses a Cassandra's `CQLSSTableWriter` that runs just fine as a standalone program but fails with `java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow` when run via `spark-submit` even on a clean local install and it doesn't even use the executors, it's just a driver! So *something* on a Spark's class path is causing it. There is some messing around with byte code because Guava 19.0 needs to be shaded for Cassandra libraries to work (Spark provides Guava 14.0). How do I go about debugging this thing?

Here's a minimal example of the problem which is still a wall of text:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Operand stack overflow
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/cassandra/config/ColumnDefinition.comparisonOrder(Lorg/apache/cassandra/config/ColumnDefinition$Kind;ZJLorg/apache/cassandra/cql3/ColumnIdentifier;)J @49: bipush
  Reason:
    Exceeded max stack size.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @49
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/cassandra/config/ColumnDefinition$Kind', integer, long, long_2nd, 'org/apache/cassandra/cql3/ColumnIdentifier' }
    stack: { long, long_2nd, long, long_2nd }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b200 429a 0019 2009 949b 000b 2014 0043
    0x0000010: 949b 000b bb00 4659 b700 4abf 2ab6 004e
    0x0000020: 8510 3d79 1b99 0009 1400 4fa7 0004 0981
    0x0000030: 2010 3079 8119 04b4 0055 1010 7d81 ad
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@20)
    same_frame(@28)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@46,Long)
    full_frame(@47,{Object[#16],Integer,Long,Object[#82]},{Long,Long})

    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns.<clinit>(Columns.java:55)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.PartitionColumns.<clinit>(PartitionColumns.java:35)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData$Builder.build(CFMetaData.java:1464)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.compile(CFMetaData.java:499)
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.compile(SchemaKeyspace.java:268)
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.<clinit>(SchemaKeyspace.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter$Builder.build(CQLSSTableWriter.java:517)
```

Job itself

```
package me.synapse.cassandra_export
import java.nio.file.Files
import org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
import org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter

object CassandraExport extends App {
  val writer = CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
    .inDirectory(Files.createTempDirectory("export").toAbsolutePath.toString)
    .forTable("CREATE TABLE my_space.my_table (id int PRIMARY KEY, value text)")
    .using("INSERT INTO my_space.my_table (id, value) VALUES(?, ?)")
    .withPartitioner(new Murmur3Partitioner())
    .build()
}
```

Build file

```
name := "cassandra_export"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies := Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2" % "provided",
  ("org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-all" % "3.11.3").exclude("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j"),
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.6.0",
  "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.56.Final" // To evict all other nettys
)

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "shaded.google.common.@1")
    .inAll //Cassandra requires Guava 19.0 while Spark provides 14.0
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList(ps@_*) if Assembly.isReadme(ps.last) || Assembly.isLicenseFile(ps.last) =>
    MergeStrategy.rename
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => {
    xs map {
      _.toLowerCase
    } match {
      case "manifest.mf" :: Nil | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps@(x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case ("spring.schemas" :: Nil) | ("spring.handlers" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.discard
    }
  }
  case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
}
```